# AWS IoT certificate suddenly fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, iot, aws-iot

I have a 2nd generation IoT button, which worked great until suddenly it didn't anymore. Now any time I hit the button I get a blinking red light: long-short-short pattern.

Amazon defines this error: "Cannot establish a secure connection with the server. This error is most likely due to an unknown or inactive certificate."

I generated a new certificate and verified this connects me successfully:

```
openssl s_client -connect <button-id-here>.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8443 -CAfile AmazonRootCA1.pem -cert certificate.pem.crt -key private.pem.key
```

But uploading the same certificate and private key to the button doesn't make the error go away. I still get long-short-short blinking.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this? What else could suddenly cause this error?

This is on my very simple home network where I have not made any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS opened a support case on my behalf citing a defect identified in certain buttons. The problem then cleared up on its own, without me issuing a new cert. So, the only resolution really is to open a support case, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having same problem. Looks like AWS aware of this issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=878035&tstart=0